# Left tail bound for stopping time of a gaussian random walk

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-walk, stopping-times, concentration-of-measure

Given a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\sim N(\mu,1)$ and define the sum (gaussian random walk) as $S_n(\mu) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. We want to say something about the quantity $N(\mu)$, which is defined as
$$
N(\mu): =\inf\left\{n\in \mathbb N^+ : e^{-\frac{1}{n}S_n(\mu)^2}\leq \alpha\right\} = \inf\left\{n\in \mathbb N^+: |S_n|\geq \sqrt{-n\log\alpha}\right\}
$$
where $\alpha = \Omega(1)\in (0,0.5)$, say $0.025$.

The distribution of $N(\mu)$ itself is untractable, but the right tail is fairly easy to be bounded via any Hoeffding-type inequality. The question is about the left tail:
$$
\mathbb P(N(\mu)\leq \beta)\text{ or any thing control N is small},
$$
where $\beta$ is presumably $\beta\sim -\log \alpha \cdot \mu^{-2}$ this order.

I found [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-5/issue-5/Power-One-Tests-Based-on-Sample-Sums/10.1214/aos/1176343943.full) and reference therein study a similar case (in a fairly general framework with weaker assumptions), but they don't consider the left tail bound.

The reason why I want to consider left tail bound is to upper bound $\text{Var}(\bar{X}_N)$ or equivalently $E[1/N]$ (or something like $E[1/N^2]$).